# Is it possible to implement voice calls with your friends with the facebook developer api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have recently implemented facebook login to my ios app with success and I recently read that it is possible to implement messenger as well so that you can chat with your facebook friends.

I was wondering though if it is also possible to implement calls or even better video calls with your friends or is the messenger function only limited to text chatting at this certain moment?

Comment: _“and I recently read that it is possible to implement messenger as well so that you can chat with your facebook friends”_ – you read wrong. Messenger platform is for bots to let a user talk to a page, not for chat between users.

Comment: @CBroe ah ok! so it is not possible at all to communicate with friends via facebook developer?

Comment: There is no API for user to user chats. Users can still send each other messages for example via the Send dialog.